# Reduce amount of case result per row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which calculates the open invoice amount per row, but an invoice can also have a partial downpayment so I want to deduct the sum of the total downpayment from the total.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT G.Bedrijfsnaam, `F`.`GebruikerID`, `F`.`Factuurnummer`, `F`.`Factuurdatum`,    `F`.`Statusdatum`, `F`.`Subtotaal` - `F`.`Korting` + `F`.`Verzendkosten` AS `Subtotaal`, `F`.`BTWPercentage`, `FS`.`Naam`, `FS`.`Openstaand`, `B`.`Dagen`, `F`.`Betaalmethode`,
CASE
   WHEN F.Factuurdatum BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND NOW()
   THEN ((`F`.`Subtotaal` - `F`.`Korting` + `F`.`Verzendkosten`) * ( 1 + (F.BTWPercentage / 100 ) ) )
END AS 13Days
FROM `Factuur` AS `F`
LEFT JOIN Betaalmethode AS B on B.ID=F.Betaalmethode
JOIN Factuurstatus AS FS ON FS.ID=F.Factuurstatus
JOIN Gebruiker AS G ON G.ID=F.GebruikerID
JOIN Betaalmethode AS BM ON BM.ID=F.Betaalmethode
WHERE FS.Openstaand = 1 
 AND F.Factuurstatus != 11 
 AND F.Factuurstatus != 6 
 AND F.Factuurstatus != 7
```

I thought i could achieve this by adding the following line to the "THEN" Line:

```
 - (SELECT SUM(Bedrag) FROM BetalingenFactuur WHERE Factuurnummer=F.Factuurnummer)
```

Which would give me

```
THEN ((`F`.`Subtotaal` - `F`.`Korting` + `F`.`Verzendkosten`) * ( 1 + (F.BTWPercentage / 100 ) ) - (SELECT SUM(Bedrag) FROM BetalingenFactuur WHERE Factuurnummer=F.Factuurnummer) )
```

But when I do this it totaly neglects all invoices without dowypayments and only gets the invoices with a downpayment.

But I want all of them, I am stuck here.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I think I have to look in the following direction, does this make sense?

```
(CASE
  WHEN F.Factuurdatum BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 9999 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 91 DAY)
  (CASE (SELECT SUM(Bedrag) FROM BetalingenFactuur WHERE Factuurnummer=F.Factuurnummer) IS NOT NULL THEN
    ((`F`.`Subtotaal` - `F`.`Korting` + `F`.`Verzendkosten`) * ( 1 + (F.BTWPercentage / 100 ) ) - (SELECT SUM(Bedrag) FROM BetalingenFactuur WHERE Factuurnummer=F.Factuurnummer) )
  ELSE
    ((`F`.`Subtotaal` - `F`.`Korting` + `F`.`Verzendkosten`) * ( 1 + (F.BTWPercentage / 100 ) ) )
  END)
END) AS 91Dagen
```

I am getting a syntax error now though, totaly stuck. 
If my question isn't clear, please let me know I will try to rephrase everything.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but all the column names not being generalized like `sum` or `id` make it really difficult to understand what you want. Also, example data and expected result (best in sql fiddle) would increase your chances of getting the question answered fast significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is 'catch' the NULL that is returned when you don't have any records in your BetalingenFactuur table, I would suggest using COALESCE instead:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Bedrag), 0) FROM BetalingenFactuur WHERE Factuurnummer=F.Factuurnummer
```

This makes it easier to read (and probably faster as well).

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.
i changed this

```
CASE
   WHEN F.Factuurdatum BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND NOW()
    THEN ((`F`.`Subtotaal` - `F`.`Korting` + `F`.`Verzendkosten`) * ( 1 + (F.BTWPercentage / 100 ) ) )
END AS 13Days
```

To

```
(CASE
   WHEN F.Factuurdatum BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND NOW() THEN
   (CASE WHEN (SELECT SUM(Bedrag) FROM BetalingenFactuur WHERE Factuurnummer=F.Factuurnummer) IS NOT NULL THEN
     ((`F`.`Subtotaal` - `F`.`Korting` + `F`.`Verzendkosten`) * ( 1 + (F.BTWPercentage / 100 ) ) - (SELECT SUM(Bedrag) FROM BetalingenFactuur WHERE Factuurnummer=F.Factuurnummer) )
    ELSE
     ((`F`.`Subtotaal` - `F`.`Korting` + `F`.`Verzendkosten`) * ( 1 + (F.BTWPercentage / 100 ) ) )
    END)
END) AS 13Days
```

Adding another case inside the exisiting case to check wether or not the invoice had any downpayments and switching the query based on that gave me the right results.